# Count dictionary keys and argmax in a list of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**Given**:

```
import numpy as np
list_of_list = [
    ['ccc', 'cccc', 'b', 'c', 'b'],
    ['ab', 'b', 'b', 'aa'], 
    ['c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c'],
    ['bb', 'd', 'c'],
]
my_dict = {key: None for key in 'abcde'}
```

`list_of_list` is simplified in this test example but it actually is a list of vocabularies in a list:

```
list_of_list = [ 
    ['word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordN'],
    ['word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordM'], 
    ['word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordK'], 
    ...
]
```

**Goal**:

I'd like to get updated dictionary with pattern: `"key": [index_of_max_occurrence, max_occurrence]` given the components of `list_of_list`.

**My inefficient solution**:

The following code snippet, using `for loop`, works fine with quite small dictionary and list of list. However, for bigger sizes, it obviously turns out to be very time consuming and inefficient:

```
for k in my_dict:
    counters = list()
    for lst in list_of_list:
        counters.append( lst.count(k) )
    if any(counters):
        my_dict[k] = [ np.argmax(counters) , max(counters) ]
print(my_dict) # {'a': None, 'b': [0, 2], 'c': [2, 4], 'd': [3, 1], 'e': None}
```

Is there any better robust solution that I could speed up my program?

Comment: If won't affect performance, but `for k, v in my_dict.items():` should be `for k in my_dict:` since you never user `v`.

Comment: Are there only letters to count or do you look for some word specificaly?

Comment: Did you read the description of the `coding-efficiency` tag? It's not about the performance of the code, it's about making the coding process easier.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto `list_of_list` is actually a list of vocabularies: `list_of_list = [ ['word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordN'], ['word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordM'], ['word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordK'], ... ]`

Comment: You can: 1. Flatten this 2D array. 2. Use a Counter (Here is a tutorial for you to use: https://realpython.com/python-counter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the `list_of_lists` to `list_of_dicts` (counters) and reduce the complexity. Alson, the `np.argmax` isn't necessary, use `enumerate`/`max`:

```py
from collections import Counter

list_of_dicts = [
    Counter(l)
    for l in list_of_list
]

for k in my_dict:
    i, m = max(enumerate(list_of_dicts), key=lambda d: d[1].get(k, 0))
    if k in m:
        my_dict[k] = [i, list_of_dicts[i][k]]

print(my_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': None, 'b': [0, 2], 'c': [2, 4], 'd': [3, 1], 'e': None}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is way more efficient and faster!